# Export data from multiple databases with one single select statement

Tags: database, export

I have 100+ websites all sitting on a single host and accessable via phpMyAdmin. Each one of these websites uses the same database structure.

I want to pull out all the profile specific information to do a mass mail to all my registered users. I'd then need to combine, sort, remove duplicates and upload to my mail client, I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT `NickName`,`FirstName`,`LastName`,`Email` FROM `Profiles`;
```

What I want to know is can I build a query where I can execute a similar statement yet pull the data from every database and just do one export? Then I can clean the data and upload and send everyone an email? Is this possible?

Comment: Can anyone help with this question please?